# ADF Service Principal can not link to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to connect to Synapse Pool via Service Principal but getting below error:

```
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'xxxxx.sql.azuresynapse.net', Database: 'xxx-sql', User: 'xxx'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
```

I've configured firewall rules. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#service-principal-authentication).
You need first **create contained database users for the service principal.**
I reproduced your problem. So did you create the user?
[image]

After I do following steps. Linked service with Service principal Authentication type works fine.

```sql
CREATE USER [ad_user_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;


EXEC sp_addrolemember db_owner, [ad_user_name];
```